# Android shell change PATH variable on init

Tags: android, adb

My current $PATH variable on Android emulator shell is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
```

I want to change it on init. In which file should I make changes?

Comment: `/system/etc/mkshrc`